# MOXy jaxb marshalling: A descriptor for class was not found

Tags: xml, junit, jaxb, marshalling, moxy

After fiddling around with an old project for some time now trying to get it to include JAXB capabilities I have hit a snag and would like some outside input if anyone can provide it. The schemagen off the same classes and many more besides works beautifully (only thanks to some other answers here on Stackoverflow from a MOXy lead, many thanks for those!) but the marshalling fails.

The exception I get:

```
[Exception [EclipseLink-25007] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.XMLMarshalException
Exception Description: A descriptor for class <edited out for anonymisation of project>.util.streamprocessor.handler.Acknowledge was not found in the project.  For JAXB, if the JAXBContext was bootstrapped using TypeMappingInfo[] you must call a marshal method that accepts TypeMappingInfo as an input parameter.]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBMarshaller.marshal(JAXBMarshaller.java:459)
    at <edited out for anonymisation of project>.util.streamprocessor.FieldMessageJaxbTest.testFieldMessageXmlTransformation(FieldMessageJaxbTest.java:98)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:117)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-25007] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.XMLMarshalException
Exception Description: A descriptor for class <edited out for anonymisation of project>..util.streamprocessor.handler.Acknowledge was not found in the project.  For JAXB, if the JAXBContext was bootstrapped using TypeMappingInfo[] you must call a marshal method that accepts TypeMappingInfo as an input parameter.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.XMLMarshalException.descriptorNotFoundInProject(XMLMarshalException.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.Context$ContextState.getSession(Context.java:137)
```

The class itself (note: I already fiddled around with the class to make it a simple pojo with just 1 field and no parents, the resulting exception upon marshalling is the same):
    @XmlRootElement
    @XmlType
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
    public class Acknowledge extends AbstractFieldObject implements ResponseProtocol, HasLocation {
        public static final int ID = 0x2199;
        public static final String NAME = "Acknowledge";

```
    public int __id__() { return ID; }
    public String __name__() { return NAME; }

    // generated from CodeGenerator.fieldDeclaration
    @XmlElement
    private java.util.Date timestamp;
    // generated from CodeGenerator.fieldDeclaration
    @XmlElement
    private AcknowledgementData data;

    @XmlElement
    private CoreMachine sourceMachine_;
    /** Get the machine from which this message originated */
    public CoreMachine getSourceMachine_() { return sourceMachine_; }
    /** Set the machine from which this message originated - FOR TESTING ONLY */
    public void setSourceMachine_(CoreMachine sourceMachine_) {
        if (sourceMachine_ == null) {
            this.sourceMachine_ = FieldMessageUtil.createAnonymousMachine(null, sourceURL_, 0);
        } else {
            this.sourceMachine_ = sourceMachine_;
        }
    }

    @XmlElement
    private URL sourceURL_;
    /** Get the URL from which this message originated */
    public URL getSourceURL_() { return sourceURL_; }
    /** Set the URL from which this message originated - FOR TESTING ONLY */
    public void setSourceURL_(URL sourceURL_) { this.sourceURL_ = sourceURL_; }

    @XmlElement
    private Date arrivalTime_;
    /** Get the time at which this message was received in the office */
    public Date getArrivalTime_() { return arrivalTime_; }
    /** Set the time at which this message was received in the office - FOR TESTING ONLY */
    public void setArrivalTime_(Date arrivalTime_) { this.arrivalTime_ = arrivalTime_; }

    @XmlElement
    private int sequenceNumber_;
    /** Get sequence number with which this message was sent from the field */
    public int getSequenceNumber_() { return sequenceNumber_; }
    /** Set sequence number with which this message was sent from the field - FOR TESTING ONLY */
    public void setSequenceNumber_(int sequenceNumber_) { this.sequenceNumber_ = sequenceNumber_; }

    @XmlElement
    private int protocolType_;
    /** Get protocol type with which this message was sent from the field */
    public int getProtocolType_() { return protocolType_; }
    /** Set protocol type with which this message was sent from the field - FOR TESTING ONLY */
    public void setProtocolType_(int protocolType_) { this.protocolType_ = protocolType_; }

    public Acknowledge() {
    }

    public Acknowledge(Packet pkt) {
        setSourceURL_(pkt.getURL());
        setSourceMachine_(pkt.getMachine());
        setArrivalTime_(pkt.date());
        setSequenceNumber_(pkt.sequenceNo());
        initFromBlock(pkt.getMessage());
    }

    public Acknowledge(Block block) {
        initFromBlock(block);
    }

    private void initFromBlock(Block block) {

        if (block == null) return;


        // generated from CodeGenerator.constructorField1
        if (block.getChild("timestamp") != null) {
            // generated from CodeGenerator.constructorField4a
            this.timestamp = block.getDate("timestamp");
        }
        // generated from CodeGenerator.constructorField1
        if (block.getChild("data") != null) {
            // generated from CodeGenerator.constructorField2
            this.data = new AcknowledgementData((Block)block.getChild("data"), this);
        }
    }


    // generated from CodeGenerator.getter0
    public java.util.Date getTimestamp() {
         return timestamp;
    }

    // generated from CodeGenerator.getter0
    public AcknowledgementData getData() {
         return data;
    }

    // generated from CodeGenerator.setter
    public void setTimestamp(java.util.Date timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    // generated from CodeGenerator.setter
    public void setData(AcknowledgementData data) {
        this.data = data;
    }


    // generated from CodeGenerator.toString1
    public String toString() { return "Acknowledge"; }

    public @Nonnull String toXML() {
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
        s.append("<Acknowledge>\n");
        // generated from CodeGenerator.toStringMachine1
        if (sourceMachine_ != null) s.append("<machine>"+sourceMachine_+"<machine>\n");
        if (sourceURL_ != null) s.append("<url>"+sourceURL_+"<url>\n");
        if (arrivalTime_ != null) s.append("<arrivalTime>"+arrivalTime_+"<arrivalTime>\n");
        // generated from CodeGenerator.toStringField2
        s.append("<timestamp>"+timestamp+"</timestamp>\n");
        // generated from CodeGenerator.toStringField1
        if (data != null) {
            // generated from CodeGenerator.toStringField2a
            s.append(data.toXML());
        }
        // generated from CodeGenerator.toString2
        s.append("</Acknowledge>\n");
        return s.toString();
    }

    public Location getLocation() { return (data != null) ? data.getLocation() : null; }
}
```

The JUnit code for marshalling/unmarshalling (without the initialContext the JUnit test would crash upon JAXBContext creation due to unmarshalling of the oxm-...xml files)

```
/**
 * Smal test trying marshalling & unmarshalling of a FieldMessage with Jaxb.
 *
 * Created by colinm2 on 14/10/2015.
 */
public class FieldMessageJaxbTest {

    @Test
    public void testFieldMessageXmlTransformation() {
        try {
            // Create initial context
            System.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
                    "org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory");
            System.setProperty(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES,
                    "org.apache.naming");
            InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Create the Object
        Acknowledge ackInput = new Acknowledge();
        Acknowledge ackOutput = new Acknowledge();
        ackInput.setArrivalTime_(new Date());
        AcknowledgementData ackData = new AcknowledgementData();
        ackData.setError(0);
        ackData.setHandle(0);
        ackData.setSize(5);
        ackInput.setData(ackData);
        ackInput.setProtocolType_(2);
        ackInput.setSequenceNumber_(1234);
        ackInput.setTimestamp(new Date());
        try {
            ackInput.setSourceURL_(new URL("http://www.google.com"));
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Create the JAXBContext
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = null;
        try {
            Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>(1);
            FileReader file1 = new FileReader("src/main/res/<edited out for anonymisation of project>./util/streamprocessor/oxm_1.xml");
            FileReader file2 = new FileReader("src/main/res/<edited out for anonymisation of project>./util/streamprocessor/oxm_2.xml");
            FileReader file3 = new FileReader("src/main/res/<edited out for anonymisation of project>./util/streamprocessor/oxm_3.xml");
            FileReader file4 = new FileReader("src/main/res/<edited out for anonymisation of project>./util/streamprocessor/oxm_4.xml");
            FileReader file5 = new FileReader("src/main/res/<edited out for anonymisation of project>./util/streamprocessor/oxm_5.xml");

            List<Object> fileList = new ArrayList<Object>();
            fileList.add(file1);
            fileList.add(file2);
            fileList.add(file3);
            fileList.add(file4);
            fileList.add(file5);
            properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.OXM_METADATA_SOURCE, fileList);
            jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Acknowledge.class.getPackage().getName(),
                    Acknowledge.class.getClassLoader(), properties);
            Marshaller m = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

            // Create the Document
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document document = db.newDocument();

            m.marshal(ackInput, document);

            // Output the Document
            TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer t = tf.newTransformer();
            DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document);
            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);
            t.transform(source, result);

            Unmarshaller u = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            ackOutput = (Acknowledge) u.unmarshal(document);
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TransformerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        assertEquals(ackInput.hashCode(), ackOutput.hashCode());
    }
}
```

edit: To make the above code work, even though I am just marshalling/unmarshalling 1 class I do have to use the classes array constructor:

```
 Class[] classes = new Class[1];
 classes[0] = Acknowledge.class;
 jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(classes, properties);
```

The working schema generator (just in case, probably not needed here):

```
/**
 * Created by colinm2 on 12/10/2015.
 */
public class XsdGenerator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Reflections reflections = new Reflections("<edited out for anonymisation of project>.util.streamprocessor.handler");

        Set<Class<? extends AbstractFieldObject>> allClasses =
                reflections.getSubTypesOf(AbstractFieldObject.class);
        Set<Class<? extends Object>> jaxbClasses = new HashSet<>();
        for (Class clazz : allClasses) {
            if (!clazz.getName().endsWith("Constants") &&
                    !clazz.getName().endsWith("MessageGenerator") &&
                    !clazz.getName().endsWith("Processor") &&
                    !clazz.getName().contains("$")){
                jaxbClasses.add(clazz);
            }
        }

        Class[] classes = jaxbClasses.toArray(new Class[jaxbClasses.size()]);
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = null;
        try {
            Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>(1);
            FileReader file1 = new FileReader("src/main/res/<edited out for anonymisation of project>/util/streamprocessor/oxm_1.xml");
            FileReader file2 = new FileReader("src/main/res/<edited out for anonymisation of project>/util/streamprocessor/oxm_2.xml");
            FileReader file3 = new FileReader("src/main/res/<edited out for anonymisation of project>/util/streamprocessor/oxm_3.xml");
            FileReader file4 = new FileReader("src/main/res/<edited out for anonymisation of project>/util/streamprocessor/oxm_4.xml");
            FileReader file5 = new FileReader("src/main/res/<edited out for anonymisation of project>/util/streamprocessor/oxm_5.xml");

            List<Object> fileList = new ArrayList<Object>();
            fileList.add(file1);
            fileList.add(file2);
            fileList.add(file3);
            fileList.add(file4);
            fileList.add(file5);
            properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.OXM_METADATA_SOURCE, fileList);
            jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(classes, properties);
            SchemaOutputResolver sor = new XsdSchemaOutputResolver();
                jaxbContext.generateSchema(sor);
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static class XsdSchemaOutputResolver extends SchemaOutputResolver {
        public Result createOutput(String namespaceURI, String suggestedFileName) throws IOException {
            File file = new File("target/generated-resources/<edited out for anonymisation of project>/util/streamprocessor/handler/" + suggestedFileName);
            file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(file);
            result.setSystemId(file.toURI().toURL().toString());
            return result;
        }

    }
}
```

Does anyone have any idea why the marshalling would not be able to find the annotations of my class Acknowledge? Any help would be appreciated, I have been bashing my head against this for too long already to find something on my own right now.

Cheers,
Michael

edit: Corrected some spelling mistakes.

Comment: Damnit, that was unexpected. A good nights sleep did wonders. In case anyone else faces issues marshalling/unmarshalling, even when doing just 1 single class, use the constructor like this have it actually find the class descriptors: Class[] classes = new Class[1];
            classes[0] = Acknowledge.class;
            jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(classes, properties);